# Where to find Titan error logs?

Tags: cassandra, titan, rexster

I'm using Titan with Cassandra, Elasticsearch and Rexster.

Everything is properly set up and I can add/remove nodes and edges to the graph through Rexster as well as the REST API.

When it crashes, I have to kill java and run it again. The error that I get in Rexster is:

> Could not get the vertices of graphs from Rexster.

It happens often and I don't know what the problem is. I'm not sure what part of the stack -- Titan, Rexster or Elasticsearch -- fails.

Where can I find a log file that I could look at to find out what the problem is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you are using Titan Server distribution.  By default there should be a `log` directory in the root of your titan installation directory.  It should contain two files:

1. cassandra.log - obviously for cassandra
2. rexstitan.log - Rexster logs.  As Rexster hosts Titan, the Titan logging messages should be in here as well.

Answer (score 1):

It also depends of your Titan configuration, whether is remote or embedded. Cassandra logs are usually stored in /var/log/cassandra/. Check there also.